# Execute a code after await function finishes

Tags: flutter

I have this scenario where I have a list of books that is populated with a listview builder via an API. And each list has an add button where a user can add the books into the local db (sqlite). I am trying to check on the tap the add button if the book already exists, the user will be alerted with a pop and won't be able to add.

This is the code where I check if the book exists in the DB or not. The function _checkBookExist gets called on the onPressed in button in the list.

My problem is, till the time SQL query gets executed, the rest of the statements finishes. Any elegant way to address the issue ? I tried using .then() and .whenComplete() but those didn't work either.

```
  _checkBookExist(id, author, title, thumbnail) async {
    final List<BookShelf> result = await bookshelfDb.bookExists(id);
   // below statements where I check if the book exist
    if (result.length == 0 || result[0].volumeid == id) {
       final booksToAdd = BookShelf(
          author: author,
          volumeid: id,
          thumbnail: thumbnail,
          title: title,
          dateAdded: date.toString()); 
         // below statements adds the book into the DB
      await bookshelfDb.addItem(booksToAdd).then((value) => {
            SnackBarMessage.snackBar(context, "Added to Bookshelf", "Ok", 2000),
          });
    } else {
      print("Book Exist");
    }

  }
```

Comment: Code after an `await` will not execute until the `await`ed `Future` completes.  If you think code is executing prematurely, then that indicates that either your `Future` is completing prematurely or you're not observing what you think you are (for example, you might be observing code being executed from an earlier call).  With what you've provided, people can only make guesses about what you're doing wrong.  If you want more help, you should provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

`await` waits until asynchronous `addItem` is executed and only after the execution of the rest continues.

```
await bookshelfDb.addItem(booksToAdd);
SnackBarMessage.snackBar(context, "Added to Bookshelf", "Ok", 2000);
```